# How to arrange order of fields of matlab structure based on order of rows of matlab table?

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x1 matlab structure data with 7 fields such as athe,bted,bdou,ccour,chr,crt,cpoy and 7x1 matlab table with rows ccour,athe,cpoy,bted,chr,bdou,crt. How I will arrange the order of matlab structure based on the order of rows of matlab table? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `orderfields`

http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html

If you have a struct `S` and a table `T`, use `T.Properties.VariableNames` to get the column names of the table:

```
orderfields(S, T.Properties.VariableNames);
```

Example:

Create a structure with 3 fields in the order (aa,cc,bb):

```
S.aa = 2;
S.cc = 3;
S.bb = 4;

S = 

aa: 2
cc: 3
bb: 4
```

Create a table from 3 variables in the order (bb, aa, cc);

```
aa = 2
bb = 3
cc = 4;
T = table(bb,aa,cc)

T = 

bb    aa    cc
__    __    __

3     2     4
```

Order fields on `S` according to the order of T variables:

```
S2 = orderfields(S, T.Properties.VariableNames)

S2 = 

bb: 4
aa: 2
cc: 3
```

Comment: Should I convert my matlab table to struct? I have a structure data and matlab data wherein I need to arrange the order of matlab structure based on the order of rows of matlab table that I have.

Comment: I updated my answwer. You can get your table column names with `T.Properties.VariableNames` and use them as the second parameter for `orderfields`

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. Check my example, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at the function [orderfields](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html).

Answer (score 0):

orderfields(structVar, fieldnames(structVar));

Comment: So you’re suggesting to reorder the fields in the same order they already were? I don’t think this code does anything... // In any case, answers on Stack Overflow should be more than just code, you need to explain how or why the code works and why it answers OP’s question.